# stopping duplicate entry in dynamodb

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table called followProduct in Dynamodb and it has following strucure

```
id - item id
email - user email
product - product id
```

Whenever a user follows a product I am making an entry in the table. I am trying to stop duplicate entry and using the following code

```
let params = {
    TableName: "followProduct",
    ConditionExpression: "email <> :email AND product <> :pid",
    Item: {
        email: "a@a.com",
        product: req.body.productId,
        id: shortid.generate()
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':email': "a@a.com",
        ":pid": req.body.productId
    }
};
createItemInDDB(params).then(() => {
    res.status(200).send("Company Added");
}, err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.sendStatus(500);
});
```

CreateItemInDDB is just a function that takes params as input and run put function provided by document client. This params is still making a duplicate entry. I want that for every email each product id should be entered only once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

can you describe your table hash-range keys?

Dynamodb can force uniqueness only for hash-range table keys (not for global secondary index keys)

from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html

> To prevent a new item from replacing an existing item, use a conditional expression that contains the attribute_not_exists function with the name of the attribute being used as the partition key for the table. Since every record must contain that attribute, the attribute_not_exists function will only succeed if no matching item exists.

and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html:

> The PutItem operation will overwrite an item with the same key (if it exists). If you want to avoid this, use a condition expression. This will allows the write to proceed only if the item in question does not already have the same key:

Comment: Id is the primary key here. 
Lets say I have an entry 1,a@a.com, pid1.... I don't want a entry like 2, a@a.com,pid1.
can it be handled using ConditionExpression. ?

Comment: so hash key is id and email is range key? in this case dynamodb can force uniqueness only for id-email. so in your case (if i understand it well), the only option for you is to add secondary index email-pid, and query on it before doing insert (use locks if multythreading). the cons in this case that if you have many records for each user(email) so you need high capacity (or you will get throughput errors)

Comment: Got that. What if I change my schema to email - hash key and product sort key. Then I just it will enforce uniqueness on the pair and I will not have a duplicate entry. ?

Comment: exactly, as I wrote above, you should use in this case attribute_not_exists